# How to connect to airserver

Tags: wireless, multiple-monitors

At work, when presenting on screens or projectors in meeting rooms, we've recently started connecting to an "airserver". This works by simply connecting to a new Wi-Fi network called "Airserver [meetingroomname]". Apparently, this works fine on both Windows and Mac without the need for installing other software, but on my Ubuntu, I see a millisecond glimpse of an "Enter password"-dialog, and then - nothing.

Can this technology be brought to work on Ubuntu, or am I doomed to forever connect my laptop via an HDMI-cable?

Comment: More details needed: So people on Windows or Macs just connect to this WiFi network and it just immediately and automatically starts using an external display? That sounds like terrible security. What is the "Enter password" dialog you see? Is it for connecting to the WiFi?

Comment: @muru Yes, and yes. Only people are prompted to share their screen.

Comment: Prompted by what? Also, if this is a paid-for product, shouldn't you be able to ask for customer support from them?

Comment: @muru Haha - yes, in principle. Only I am not the one who bought this product - my workplace did. And they accept that I run Ubuntu, but they don't support it. So I have to find my own solutions...